# A simple map using Mapbox API not working?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I am using Mapbox API to create simple maps and learn. I have written a very simple code to display the centre on some coordinates but the map won't show.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>A simple map</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.5/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.5/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoicm9oYW4wNzkzIiwiYSI6IjhFeGVzVzgifQ.MQBzoHJmjH19bXDW0b8nKQ';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', {
    center: [28.611690, 77.191008],
    zoom: 13
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong parameters for `L.mapbox.map`, the first element is correct, that's for the ID of a HTML element or a reference to an HTML element. The second however, isn't for the options object. The second is for your mapbox mapid (or url, or tilejson), which you get when you create your own map via the Mapbox editor: https://www.mapbox.com/editor/#app The third parameter is for the options object.

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicGF1bC12ZXJob2V2ZW4iLCJhIjoiZ1BtMWhPSSJ9.wQGnLyl1DiuIQuS0U_PtiQ';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-i86nkdio', {
    center: [28.611690, 77.191008],
    zoom: 13
});
```